# Using OR in views Argument filter

Tags: views

Is it possible to use OR in arguments? 
I have content types "Sport Match" and "Sport Team". "Sport Team" can be in "Host" field or in "Guest" field of Sport Match (node reference).
How can i make view containing all "Sport Match" for one "Sport Team"? I would like to display such view on every "Sport Team" node. So i'm thinking that simple two arguments with OR would to the trick.

I would like to get NID of current "Sport team" node and pass it to arguments filter which will looks something like this:

field_host = NID

OR

field_guest = NID

Is there way to do this in views?

In SQL this is easy, can anyone point me how alter view so I manualy insert OR filter.

Or some other idea how to do this?

(I'm using D6 and Views 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd convert that argument into a filter, then use http://drupal.org/project/views_or for it.

To convert an argument into a filter, you can use hook_views_query_substitutions or hook_views_pre_view to replace a specific value (for example `***NID***`) with what you need (e.g. `arg(1)`).